# Why does Google Voice Typing transcribe certain words incorrectly, and not offer alternatives?

Tags: voice-recognition, spell-check, voice-typing

There are a few words that I use in everyday conversation that Google Voice Typing doesn't seem to want to recognize.  The first is "extraordinarily."  It always transcribed "extraordinary Lee."  The other two words (in censored format, since I imagine vulgarities are kinda frowned on in the forums) are the s-word with the suffix "ty" appended, and the mf-word.  The former is always transcribed with only one T.  The latter is spelled without the C.

I swear a great deal.  It's how I talk.  I'm also a stickler for proper spelling and punctuation, so it bothers me that Google spells cusswords like a fourth grader, in addition to the other typo.  Also, recently it seems that all the options for corrections have disappeared--every time I dictate something, there are NO words underlined at the end.  What gives?  Anybody got any input on this?

Comment: If I say "extra (pause) ordinarily" it writes extraordinarily out as 2 words, so that may be a small bandage. But obviously it's not good enough, and I'd love to know a way to train Google Voice too.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does Google Voice Typing transcribe certain words incorrectly, and not offer alternatives?

The Google voice  typing does offer some alternatives:

[image]

Tested on Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6 and Gboard keyboard.

Comment: Is it possible that alternative words were not presented when the OP wrote their question?   Also, did Google Voice Typing ever exist outside of Gboard?   BTW, your screenshot is fantastic, especially with your avatar photo at the top!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket  alternative words may indeed not have been presented when the OP wrote their question. I recall having the same problem a few years ago. I don't recall whether Google Voice Typing ever existed outside of Gboard. Thanks, yes pretty amazing the resolution of current phones!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  What I would love to see is quality ***offline*** voice typing, and preferably not from Google!  I spend too much time correcting words I tried to type with my oversized fingers... and in lieu of a good voice typing tool for Android, I'm still searching for an offline swipe-to-type keyboard with high accuracy.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes I wish benchmarks were made more often https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/pdfs/interspeech_2018/dernoncourt18_interspeech.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link.  BTW, I just posted this related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244537/do-any-versions-of-googles-voice-typing-work-completely-offline

Comment: I just opened the link you provided... I see you're one of the authors... fantastic!