# Do any versions of Google's "Voice Typing" work completely offline?

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition, gboard, offline, voice-typing

Do any versions of Google's "Voice Typing" work completely offline?

Note that when I specify ***"completely offline"***, I mean with absolutely no data sent to Google or other parties.

Answer (score 1):

Google's "Voice Typing" can work completely offline on Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10 and Google Pixel 6 with Android 12, provided you downloaded their speech to text model:

[image]

Turn off "voice contributions" as well if you don't want Google annotators to listen to you (note that they're not supposed to link audio snippets with speakers, so it's supposed to be anonymous).

Comment: Thanks Franck.  One of my concerns with *anything* Google-based is that, even if their keyboard is blocked from sending data, they *could* use another one of their processes to upload keyboard/voice data to their servers.  After all, Google is the company that drove around collecting people's WiFi data (not just the SSIDs) and then claimed they didn't know that's what their software was doing.  They must truly think each and every person in the world is incredibly naïve to believe a nonsensical story like that.  Regardless, I appreciate the info you provided here.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket agreed, would be worth an infosec audit (esp. since they don't  make any commitment on 
 whether the text will be sent to Google servers).